# Condition on joined table faster than condition on reference

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a query involving two tables: table `A` has lots of rows, and contains a field called `b_id`, which references a record from table `B`, which has about 30 different rows. Table `A` has an index on `b_id`, and table `B` has an index on the column `name`.

My query looks something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(A.id) FROM A INNER JOIN B ON B.id = A.b_id WHERE (B.name != 'dummy') AND <condition>;
```

With `condition` being some random condition on table `A` (I have lots of those, all exhibiting the same behavior).

This query is extremely slow (taking north of 2 seconds), and using explain, shows that query optimizer starts with table `B`, coming up with about 29 rows, and then scans table `A`. Doing a `STRAIGHT_JOIN`, turned the order around and the query ran instantaneously.

I'm not a fan of black magic, so I decided to try something else: come up with the id for the record in `B` that has the name `dummy`, let's say 23, and then simplify the query to:

```
SELECT COUNT(A.id) FROM A WHERE (b_id != 23) AND <condition>;
```

To my surprise, this query was actually slower than the straight join, taking north of a second.

Any ideas on why the join would be faster than the simplified query?

UPDATE: following a request in the comments, the outputs from explain:

Straight join:

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-----------------+---------+---------+---------------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys   | key     | key_len | ref           | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-----------------+---------+---------+---------------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | A     | ALL    | b_id            | NULL    | NULL    | NULL          | 200707 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | B     | eq_ref | PRIMARY,id_name | PRIMARY | 4       | schema.A.b_id |     1  | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-----------------+---------+---------+---------------+--------+-------------+
```

No join:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | A     | ALL  | b_id          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 200707 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
```

UPDATE 2:
Tried another variant:

`SELECT COUNT(A.id) FROM A WHERE b_id IN (<all the ids except for 23>) AND <condition>;`

This runs faster than the no join, but still slower than the join, so it seems that the inequality operation is responsible for part of the performance hit, but not all.

Comment: Does `b.id` have an index?

Comment: An `EXPLAIN` of those 2 can tell you a lot, it may very well be MySQL chooses indexes that aren't optimal in the second one, but is forced by the `JOIN` to consider an index on `b_id` which is actually more beneficial. My advise would be: look at the `EXPLAIN`'s, look at the possible indexes, play around with `FORCE INDEX` in a test-environment on the possibilities (avoid them in production unless you are _very super sure_), and consider compoind indexes if your current individual indexes are less then optimal and you often need to combine more then 1 in your conditions.

Comment: The only guess I could offer is that Table `A` is not at all or poorly indexed, while Table `B` is indexed perfectly.  So, after JOIN it's possible to use indexes of `B`.

Comment: @EugenRieck yes, it does

Comment: @Wrikken no key is being used on `A`, either with or without the join.  The primary key (on id) is used on `B` with the straight join, and the index on `name` with the regular join.

Comment: One more: Try `A INNER JOIN B ON  A.b_id = B.id` instead of `A INNER JOIN B ON B.id = A.b_id` and report back. I have seen this a lot, but not in recent MySQL versions.

Comment: @PM77-1 Not sure how that will explain it. 1. Most of table `A` is used either way. 2. The query is only efficient with a straight join, meaning the DB is going over every record in table `A` (no key is being used), and finds the matching record in `B`. Without the straight join, i.e. scanning `B` and then querying `A`, the query is at its slowest

Comment: So, a full table scan of `A` either way.. hmm. Are there any indexes on A that are just not used, or no indexes? And could you share the `EXPLAIN` output with us?

Comment: `INNER JOIN B on B.id = A.b_id AND B.name != 'dummy' WHERE <condition>`

Comment: @EugenRieck still slow :(

Comment: @Wrikken Added explain outputs to the question

Comment: @elzaer Faster than no join, way slower than straight join

Comment: Weirdness indeed. If you drop the rest of all the conditions, does it still exhibit this behavior?

Comment: With `JOIN` it uses `Primary Key` of table `B`.

Comment: @Wrikken blazingly fast, but any condition I add slows it down considerably (this makes sense since it can use the `b_id` index)

Comment: @PM77-1 Yes, but it uses it to match the rows of `B` to `A`, while doing a full scan on `A`

Comment: OK, so, hm... The rest of those conditions: are those simple matches `colname='somevalue'`, or does data need to be cast /altered in some way? If MySQL cannot (or doesn't want to) use indexes, it may be that very very process of comparing rows to your conditions is quite time-consuming if done for every row, and you have little control over in which order it does this. If this is the case, I would say that `SELECT COUNT(A.id) FROM A FORCE INDEX (b_id) WHERE (b_id!=23)  AND ..` should be a bit faster then the `STRAIGHT_JOIN`  (maybe barely noticeable, but at least not slower).

Comment: @Wrikken That would make sense if a lot of records had `b_id=21` but the number of such records is actually ~2.5%

Comment: Hm, also a question, whether the cardinality of `b_id` is correctly set. Try to compare the output from `SHOW INDEXES FROM A;` _before and after_ running `ANALYZE TABLE A;`.

Comment: And `b_id=21` != `b_id!=23`, or is that so in your dataset? In that case, you have the problem of an unevenly distributed key, [of which the manual states](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/glossary.html#glos_cardinality): _"If the values in a column have a very uneven distribution, the cardinality might not be a good way to determine the best query plan. .. In such a case, you might need to use index hints to pass along advice about which lookup method is more efficient for a particular query."_ (which is the `FORCE INDEX` I suggested).

Comment: @Wrikken Analyze didn't help much. Yeah, meant 23, not 21. Forcing the index only makes it slower

Comment: OK, and no `LIMIT` clause or anything? 'cause the only thing I can think is having a certain b_id increases the chances of meeting the other conditions, earlier satisfying the requirements. And on a side note: you _did_ rule out the query cache I hope?

Comment: query cache ruled out, no limit. Completely clueless here...

Comment: Yeah... save for running mysqld with gdb (the horror...) I've run out of ideas as well.

Comment: Forgive me for asking, but for absolute certainty could you clarify how you have ruled out the query cache?

Comment: @OnFreund: could you add the possible causes and why you ruled them from the comments to the question perhaps? Makes a weirder story, and apparantly, usual suspects don't apply...

Comment: @eggyal By using `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE`

Answer (score 4):

If you are using MySQL 5.6 or later then you can ask the query optimizer what it is doing;

```
SET optimizer_trace="enabled=on";

## YOUR QUERY 
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM transactions WHERE (id < 9000) and user != 11;
##END YOUR QUERY

SELECT trace FROM information_schema.optimizer_trace;

SET optimizer_trace="enabled=off";
```

You will almost certainly need to refer to the following sections in the MySQL reference [Tracing the Optimiser](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/optimizer-tracing.html) and [The Optimizer](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/optimizer.html)

---

Looking at the first explain it appears that the query is quicker probably because the optimizer can use the table `B` to filter down to the rows required based on the join and then use the foreign key to get the rows in table `A`.

In the explain it's this bit that is interesting; there is only one row matching and it's using `schema.A.b_id`. Effectively this is pre-filtering the rows from `A` which is where I think the performance difference comes from.

```
   | ref           | rows   | Extra       |
   | schema.A.b_id |     1  | Using where |
```

So, as is usual with queries it is all down to indexes - or more accurately missing indexes. Just because you have indexes on individual fields it doesn't necessarily mean that these are suitable for the query you're running.

Basic rule: If the `EXPLAIN` doesn't say **Using Index** then you need to add a suitable index.

Looking at the explain output the first interesting thing is ironically the last thing on each line; namely the `Extra`

In the first example we see

```
|  1 | SIMPLE      | A     | .... Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | B     | ...  Using where |
```

Both of these **Using where** is not good; ideally at least one, and preferably both should say **Using index**

When you do

```
SELECT COUNT(A.id) FROM A WHERE (b_id != 23) AND <condition>;
```

and see **Using where** then  you need to add an index as it's doing a table scan.

for example if you did

```
EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(A.id) FROM A WHERE (Id > 23)
```

You should see **Using where; Using index** (assuming here that Id is the primary key and has an index)

If you then added a condition onto the end

```
EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(A.id) FROM A WHERE (Id > 23) and Field > 0
```

and see **Using where** then you need to add an index for the two fields. Just having an index on a field doesn't mean that MySQL will be able to use that index during the query across multiple fields - this is something that internally the query optimizer will decide upon. I'm not exactly certain of the internal rules; but generally adding an extra index to match the query helps immensely.

So adding an index (on the two fields in the query above):

```
ALTER TABLE `A` ADD INDEX `IndexIdField` (`Id`,`Field`)
```

should change it such that when querying based upon those two fields there is an index.

I've tried this on one of my databases that has `Transactions` and `User` tables.

I'll use this query

```
EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(*) FROM transactions WHERE (id < 9000) and user != 11;
```

Running without index on the two fields:

```
PRIMARY,user    PRIMARY 4   NULL    14334   Using where
```

Then add an index:

```
ALTER TABLE `transactions` ADD INDEX `IndexIdUser` (`id`, `user`);
```

Then the same query again and this time

```
PRIMARY,user,Index 4    Index 4 4   NULL    12628   Using where; Using index
```

This time it's using the indexes - and as a result will be a lot quicker.

---

From comments by @Wrikken - and also bear in mind that I don't have the accurate schema / data so some of this investigation has required assumptions about the schema (which may be wrong)

```
SELECT COUNT(A.id) FROM A FORCE INDEX (b_id)

would perform at least as good as 

SELECT COUNT(A.id) FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.b_id = B.id.
```

If we look at the first EXPLAIN in the OP we see that there are two elements to the query. Referring to the [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain-output.html#jointype_eq_ref) documentation for *eq_ref* I can see that this is going to define the rows for consideration based on this relationship.

The order of the explain output doesn't necessarily mean it's doing one and then the other; it's simply what has been chosen to execute the query (at least as far as I can tell).

For some reason the query optimizer has decided not to use the index on `b_id` - I'm assuming here that because of the query the optimizer has decided that it will be more efficient to do a table scan.

The second explain concerns me a little because it's not considering the index on `b_id`; possibly because of the `AND <condition>` (which is omitted so I'm guessing as to what it could be). When I try this with an index on `b_id` it does use the index; but as soon as a condition is added it doesn't use the index.

So, when doing

```
  SELECT COUNT(A.id) FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.b_id = B.id.
```

This all *indicates* to me is that the PRIMARY index on `B` is where the speed difference is coming from; I'm assuming because of the `schema.A.b_id` in the explain that there is a Foreign key on this table; which must be a better collection of related rows than the index on `b_id` - so the query optimizer can use this relationship to define which rows to pick - and because a primary index is better than secondary indexes it's going to be much quicker to select rows out of B and then use the relationship link to match against the rows in A.

Comment: From the comments: a `FORCE INDEX` on `b_id` on the query without the `JOIN` still makes it slower then _with_ the `JOIN` (which chooses the `b_id` index usually)...

Comment: I've never used FORCE INDEX; whilst apparently there are times (http://www.mysqldiary.com/the-battle-between-force-index-and-the-query-optimizer/)  when the optimizer is picking the wrong index I'm fairly sure that the getting the indexing strategy right especially for this case which seems reasonably simple compared to some queries (for which the optimizer may need a hint).

Comment: Well, the point of this question is: we have a given query. We are not out to _optimize_ that query, we are out for an explanation _why adding a `JOIN`_ makes it run faster. It's a good explanation of how to determine which indexes may be needed (although the OP states there's a lot of 'random' conditions to add, so unless we get a more or less complete `CREATE TABLE` statement & a list of all/most used conditions, we can say little about it). It however does not explain the core question: why is the `JOIN` faster then without the `JOIN`? (Which is why I added the bounty anyway ;) )

Comment: I thought I'd answered that -) the two cases are different because there aren't enough indexes. It's hard to be definitive without the schema and the data; but I'm fairly sure that the answer to why the JOIN is faster is because there aren't enough indexes - so using the join is helping the query optimiser to reduce the number of rows to scan. Table scans are the enemy of performance and if by luck you do a query that looks like it should be slower but isn't it's because both queries are sub optimal and indexes are needed.

Comment: If that were the case, `SELECT COUNT(A.id) FROM A FORCE INDEX (b_id)` would perform at least as good as `SELECT COUNT(A.id) FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.b_id = B.id`.

Comment: see amended answer; basically I think this must be due to the relationships allowing the optimizer to more easily locate the rows when joining. In my experimentation the difference between the two isn't huge in either case. must resist urge to mention adding the right indexes again....

Comment: Thanks. Very thorough answer, and you're right in that adding a condition with an index to the query makes it run faster (+1 for that). As @Wrikken pointed out though, it still doesn't address the question. As for the first explain, you mentioned that second line should optimally have 'using index', but note that's the explain for the query that actually runs the fastest

Comment: @OnFreund the first query is quicker I think because the optimiser can use the other table to filter down to the rows required and then use the foreign key to get back to the first table. Both explains should say "using index" at the end (as a minimum).

Comment: I've revised to make my answer to the OQ clear. I'm pretty sure that this is because the JOIN allows pre-filtering of the rows in A based on the foreign key to B; which is not an option for the second query

Comment: I might be missing something here, but it's still not clear to me why going over table B first has any advantage. In either case, the end result is using almost all of the records in A, except for a very small subset.

Comment: The only way to find this out is to either post the schema and data together with queries so that I can properly analyse if; or if you're on 5.6 t then it's best to ask the optimizer; I've revised the answer to include how to do this. Post the optimizer trace for both queries and we'll be able to figure out properly why this is happening

Answer (score 2):

I do not see any strange behavior here. What you need is to understand the basics of how MySQL uses indexes. Here is an article I usually recommend: [3 ways MySQL uses indexes](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/09/12/3-ways-mysql-uses-indexes/).

It is always funny to observe people writing things like `WHERE (B.name != 'dummy') AND <condition>`, because this `AND <condition>` might be the reason why MySQL optimizer chose the specific index, and there is no valid reason to compare the performance of the query with that of another one with `WHERE b_id != 23 AND <condition>`, because the two queries usually need different indexes to perform good.

One thing you should understand, is that MySQL likes equality comparisons, and does not like range conditions and inequality comparisons. It is usually better to specify the correct values than to use a range condition or specify a `!=` value.

So, let's compare the two queries.

**With straight join**

For each row in the A.id order (which is the primary key and is clustered, that is data is stored in its order on disk) take data for the row from disk to check if your `<condition>` is met and b_id, then (I repeat for each matching row) find the appropriate row for b_id, go on disk, take b.name, compare it with 'dummy'. Even though this plan in not at all efficient, you have only 200000 rows in your A table, so that it seems rather performant.

**Without straight join**

For each row in table B compare if name is matching, look into the A.b_id index (which is obviously sorted by b_id, since it is an index, hence contains A.ids in random order), and for each A.id for the given A.b_id find the corresponding A row on disk to check the `<condition>`, if it matches count the id, otherwise, discard the row.

As you see, there is nothing strange in the fact that the second query takes so long, you basically force MySQL to randomly access almost each row in A table, where in the first query you read the A table in the order it is stored on disk.

The query with no join does not use any index at all. It actually should take about the same as the query with straight join. My guess is that the order of the `b_id!=23` and `<condition>` is significant.

UPD1: Could you still compare the performance of your query without join with the following:

```
SELECT COUNT(A.id)
FROM A
WHERE IF(b_id!=23, <condition>, 0);
```

UPD2: the fact the you do not see an index in EXPLAIN does not mean that no index is used at all. An index is at least used to define the reading order: when there is no other useful index, it is usually the primary key, but, as I said above, when there is an equility condition and the corresponding index, MySQL will use the index. So, basically, to understand which index is used you can look at the order in which rows are output. If the order is the same as the primary key, than no index was used (that is the primary key index was used), if the order of rows is shuffled - than there was some other index involved.

In your case, the second condition seems to be true for most of the rows, but the index is still used, that is to get b_id MySQL goes on disk in random order, that's why it is slow. No black magic here, and this second condition does affect the performance.

Comment: Good answer regarding with vs without straight join (+1 for that). The main question, however, is why is straight join faster than no join. The order does not seem to be significant.

Comment: @OnFreund, still, can you shed some light on the additional conditions you apply (and the data types of those other fields), because I can not reproduce the behavior you describe on similar data that I have. It all looks here as I described.

Comment: It seems like the other condition contains `LIKE`, or `MATCH`, or some other string function on a long string value.

Comment: The other conditions vary, but they're usually some combination of a boolean field being equal to true, and some date range

Comment: @OnFreund, could you check the query from my update?

Comment: Twice as fast when condition doesn't have an index, no change when it does (even though the index is not used either way in the IF variant). I'm guessing that forcing MySQL to evaluate `b_id != 23` first is the key here? That's still strange since this is true for over 95% of the records

Comment: Actually none of the variants return the result in the primary key order

Comment: Slight clarification to my previous comment: the records are not ordered by primary key when there is no index on condition, regardless of join or no join. When condition does use an indexed column, the order is by primary key, once again regardless of join or no join. In either case, join and no join share the same order, so that doesn't seem to explain the difference

Answer (score 0):

Probably this should be a comment rather than an answer but it will be a bit long.

First of all, it is hard to believe that two queries that have (almost) exactly the same explain run at different speed. Furthermore, this is less likely if the one with the extra line in the explain runs faster. And I guess the word *faster* is the key here.

You've compared speed (the time it takes for a query to finish) and that is an extremely empiric way of testing. For example, you could have improperly disabled the cache, which makes that comparison useless. Not to mention that your `<insert your preferred software application here>` could have made a page fault or any other operation at the time you've run the test that could have resulted in a decrease of the query speed.

The right way of measuring query performance is based on the explain (that's why it is there)

So the closest thing I have to answer the question: *Any ideas on why the join would be faster than the simplified query?*... is, in short, a layer 8 error.

I do have some other comments, though, that should be taken into account in order to speed things up. If `A.id` is a primary key (the name smells like it is), according to your explain, why does the `count(A.id)` have to scan all the rows? It should be able to get the data directly from the index but I don't see the `Using index` in the extra flags. It seems you don't even have a unique index on and that it is not a non nullable field. That also smells odd. Make sure that the field is not null and that there is a unique index on it, run the explain again, confirm the extra flags contain the `Using index` and then (properly) time the query. It should run much faster.

Also note that an approach that would result in the same performance improvement as I mentioned above would be to replace `count(A.id)` with `count(*)`.

Just my 2 cents.

Comment: Thanks. A.id is indeed a primary key and is defined properly. `count(*)` and `count(id)` have the same running time

Answer (score 0):

Because MySQL will not use index for `index!=val` in where.

The optimizer will decide to use an index by guessing. As a "!=" will more likely fetch everything, it skip and prevent using index to reduce overhead. (yes, mysql is stupid, and it does not statistic index column)

You may do a faster SELECT, by using `index in(everything other then val)`, that MySQL will learn to use the index.

[Example here showing query optimizer will choose to not use index by value](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/485ea/1)

Comment: `MySQL will not use index for index!=val in where` => You seem to be confusing the fact of scanning all records and using an index. You can do both as you can see in this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4de5ca/1). That is what I'm advising to do in my answer: not scanning the rows themselves, only the index

Comment: See this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/485ea/1 . For a larger table, and un-balanced key, SQL optimizer will do differently. The "index" remain "null" even "POSSIBLE_KEYS" is not.

Comment: I mentioned this in the comments, most records will actually have this part `(B.id != 23)` evaluate to true, so using the index on it should not make a major difference

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is actually a very simple consequence of algorithm design:

- **The key difference between these two queries is the *merge* operation.**

Before I give a lesson on algorithms, I will mention the reason why the merge operation improves the performance. The merge improves the performance because it reduces the overall load on the aggregation. This is an iteration vs recursion issue. In the iteration analogy, we are simply looping through the entire index and counting the matches. In the recursion analogy, we are dividing and conquering (so to speak); or in other words, we are filtering the results that we need to count, thus reducing the volume of numbers we actually need to count.

Here are the key questions:

- **Why is a merge sort faster than an insertion sort?**
- **Is a merge sort *always* faster than an insertion sort?**

Let's explain this with a parable:

Let's say we have a deck of playing cards, and we need to sum the numbers of playing cards that have the numbers 7, 8 and 9 (assuming we don't know the answer in advance).

Let's say that we decide upon two ways to solve this problem:

1. We can hold the deck in one hand and move the cards to the table, one by one, counting as we go.
2. We can separate the cards into two groups: black suits and red suits. Then we can perform step 1 upon one of the groups and reuse the results for the second group.

If we choose option 2, then we have divided our problem in half. As a consequence, we can count the matching black cards and multiply the number by 2. **In other words, we are re-using the part of the query execution plan that required the counting.** This reasoning especially works when we know in advance how the cards were sorted (aka "clustered index"). Counting half of the cards is obviously much less time consuming than counting the entire deck.

If we wanted to improve the performance yet again, depending on how large the size of our database is, we may even further consider sorting into four groups (instead of two groups): clubs, diamonds, hearts, and spades. Whether or not we want to perform this further step depends on whether or not the overhead of sorting the cards into the additional groups is justified by the performance gain. In small numbers of cards, the performance gain is likely not worth the extra overhead required to sort into the different groups. As the number of cards grows, the performance gain begins to outweigh the overhead cost.

Here is an excerpt from **"Introduction to Algorithms, 3rd edition,"** (Thomas H. Cormen, Charles E. Leiserson, Ronald L. Rivest, Clifford Stein):
(Note: If someone can tell me how to format the sub-notation, I will edit this to improve readability.)

(Also, keep in mind that "n" is the number of objects we are dealing with.)

> "As an example, in Chapter 2, we will see two algorithms for sorting.
>      The ﬁrst, known as insertion sort, takes time roughly equal to c1n2
>      to sort n items, where c1 is a constant that does not depend on n.
>      That is, it takes time roughly proportional to n2.  The second, merge
>      sort, takes time roughly equal to c2n lg n, where lg n stands for
>      log2 n and c2 is another constant that also does not depend on n.
>      Insertion sort typically has a smaller constant factor than merge
>      sort, so that c1  < c2. We shall see that the constant factors can
>      have far less of an impact on the running time than the dependence on
>      the input size n. Let’s write insertion sort’s running time as c1n ·
>      n and merge sort’s running time as c2n · lg n. Then **we see that where
>      insertion sort has a factor of n in its running time, merge sort has
>      a factor of lg n, which is much smaller.** (For example, when n = 1000,
>      lg n is approximately 10, and when n equals one million, lg n is
>      approximately only 20.) **Although insertion sort usually runs faster
>      than merge sort for small input sizes, once the input  size n becomes
>      large enough, merge sort’s advantage of lg n vs. n will more than
>      compensate for the difference in constant factors.** No matter how much
>      smaller c1 is than c2, there will always be a crossover point beyond
>      which merge sort is faster."

Why is this relevant? Let us look at the query execution plans for these two queries. We will see that there is a merge operation caused by the inner join.

Comment: there is nothing about merge in EXPLAIN, and I do not see how an index merge can even be applied here.

Comment: The merge operation can be seen when viewing the query execution plan in Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2. I will try running the query in MySQL over the weekend.

Comment: Can somebody please post the output of an EXPLAIN EXTENDED and subsequent SHOW WARNINGS\G ?

Comment: (For each of the two queries in MySQL.)